# Calculate distances between 2 given words of sample text

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I am looking for a method to output distance (amount of whitespace separated words) to console between 2 given ones. Consider following `.txt` input:

```
[SEP] Today I went to school for the first time . [/SEP] [SEP] Everyone was excited to see me ! [/SEP]
```

I now need to get distance between `[SEP]` and `[/SEP]` in this case it would be 9 and 6.

Real `.txt` input as you might guess is much longer.

UPDATE: My approach so far (splitting into array):

```
var text = "[SEP] Today I went to school for the first time . [/SEP] [SEP] Everyone was excited to see me ! [/SEP]";
var textArray = text.split(/\[SEP\]|\[\/SEP\]/);
```

UPDATE: Matching to regex provided in comments

```
var text = "[SEP] Today I went to school for the first time . [/SEP] [SEP] Everyone was excited to see me ! [/SEP]";
var matchText = text.match("\[[A-Z]+\]([^[]+)\[\/[A-Z]+\]");
```

UPDATE: Using .exec()

```
var myText = \[[A-Z]+\]([^[]+)\[\/[A-Z]+\].exec('[SEP] Today I went to school for the first time . [/SEP] [SEP] Everyone was excited to see me ! [/SEP]')
```

Comment: Can SEP tags get in multiple levels ? (e.q. [SEP] bla [SEP] bla2 [/SEP] bla3 [/SEP]

Comment: @mihai.ciorobea good point, but in my case they don't

Comment: @Tushar my bad, added code I have at the moment, to put words into array

Comment: Use regex [`\[[A-Z]+\]([^[]+)\[\/[A-Z]+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/tU9xB7/1). Get the number of words in the first captured group.

Comment: You can play with this regex helper to find what you want https://regex101.com/

Comment: **Steps:** 1. Match all the string with above regex. 2. Get capturing group 1 3. Get the number of words in the matched string.

Comment: @Tushar at the moment it only matches first bit of the text and gets rid of everything else, I'm trying to figure out a for loop that grabs it group by group, but can't get it working. Once matched, how can I go through it step by step i.e. get each group?

Comment: Ok, use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) with `while` loop.

Comment: @Tushar I'm having issues with escaping in your original regular expression, updated question with .exec, I get Illegal error in console.

Comment: @Ilja You shouldn't have done it(_you know what I mean_). Regex in JS, are delimited by slashes /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split your text using `split`. This will provide the list of words between SEP.

```
"[SEP]this is [/SEP] an interesting [SEP] thing[/SEP]".split(/\[SEP\]|\[\/SEP\]/)
```

After that you can determine each group size using

```
words.length - words.replace(/ /g,'').length
```

Full solution:

```
var wordGroups = "[SEP]this is [/SEP] an interesting [SEP] thing[/SEP]".split(/\[SEP\]|\[\/SEP\]/)
wordGroups.forEach(function(wordGroup) {
    wordGroup = wordGroup.trim()
    if (wordGroup.length == 0 ) {
        return
    }
    var nrOfWords = wordGroup.length - wordGroup.replace(/ /g,'').length + 1
    console.log("\"" + wordGroup + "\" has " + nrOfWords + " words")
})
```